# JSON couldn't be parsed using Swift Decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift, facebook, parsing

### Parsing JSON Swift 4

The idea is to get all events of a Facebook page and I don't want to use the Facebook API. The problem is that it doesn't parse. Here are all the files and the code that might help you understand the problem:

#### From a URL I get this this JSON data:

```
{
 "events": {
   "data": [
      {
    "description": "Les groupes Do Lung, BROKEN CASH MACHINE et Hobe font aussi leur rentrée en septembre ! Venez très nombreux à ce magnifique concert au Quartier Général d'Oberkampf à 20h30 ! Do Lung entame la soirée avec un set de 45min endiablé, la soirée enchaîne avec BROKEN CASH MACHINE pour une heure de Post-Rock et enfin Hobe fini la soirée avec un son rock alternatif.
    Le lieu : https://www.facebook.com/QuartierGeneralOberkampf/",
    "end_time": "2017-09-22T00:00:00+0200",
    "name": "Concert au Quartier Général d'Oberkampf !",
    "place": {
      "name": "Quartier Général Oberkampf",
      "location": {
        "city": "Paris",
        "country": "France",
        "latitude": 48.865731081726,
        "longitude": 2.3771667480469,
        "street": "103 Rue Oberkampf",
        "zip": "75011"
      },
      "id": "581262352022480"
    },
    "start_time": "2017-09-21T20:30:00+0200",
    "id": "463762790669327"
  }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": { 
       "before":"QVFIUnBKbUFfSFl",
       "after": "QVFIUlFWMWFUTWt6ZAWxRRW16c"
       }
     }
   },
"id": "757545174356489"
}
```

Excuse me if it's not perfectly placed. But I'm pretty sure you get the code. I also put only one event. But there are many in the data[].

#### All my structs in Swift:

```
struct requestEvent: Decodable {
    var events: Events
    var id: String
}

struct Events: Decodable {
    var eventList: [Event]
    var paging: Paging

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case eventList = "data"
        case paging
    }
}

struct Paging: Decodable {
    var cursors: Cursors
}

struct Cursors: Decodable {
    var before: String
    var after: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case before
        case after
    }
}

struct Event: Decodable {
     var description: String
     var endTime: String
     var name: String
     var place: Place
     var startTime: String
     var id: String

     private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case description
         case endTime = "end_time"
         case name
         case place
         case startTime = "start_time"
         case id
     }
}

struct Place: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var location: Location
    var id: String
}

struct Location: Decodable {
    var city: String
    var country: String
    var latitude: Float?
    var longitude: Float?
    var street: String
    var zip: String
}
```

#### And finally my code

```
guard let Request = try? JSONDecoder().decode(requestEvent.self,
     from: cleanData) else {
            print("Couldn't Parse data")
            return
        }
```

Alright I know it's a bit long, but I really need help. And it might be easy for most of you.

Of course when I launch the app I get "Couldn't Parse data" and I know that 'data' has the good data as I print it every time.

#### Edit

I added '?' to the id and the location of the struct place. And it seams to work fine. Thanks for your answer, but it's quite a mystery for me haha!

Comment: Add a catch clause and log the error. You probably have a mismatch between the structure/data types of your object graph and the structure/data types of your JSON. I don't have the time to cross-check that, but if you log your error it should help you track it down.)

Comment: Your json is invalid because your description value has an unescaped line break in it.

Comment: It's probably unvalid when I paste the code. As it is the code sent by Facebook, I don't think they use unvalid json code. But still thanks, I added a print of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is malformed. The line feed in the middle of the description field is invalid (replace it with `\n`).

Either that or the description value is unterminated and the `Le lieu` key is not properly quoted.

And stop throwing away the error that is thrown.

```
do 
{
    let request = try JSONDecoder().decode(requestEvent.self, from: cleanData)
}
catch 
{
   print("Couldn't Parse data because... \(error)")
}
```

would print an error message that would probably help with debugging.

Comment: Thanks, "le lieu" is not a key, it is still in the description. However here is the error that I get: "No value associated with key location (\"location\")."